# Why IntelliJ IDEA pops an error like that?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have tried many things, deleted caches, .xml and nothing worked. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\???? ?????\.IdeaIC2018.2\system\compile-server\projects_f1bd646f\timestamps\data
java.io.IOException: Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\???? ?????\.IdeaIC2018.2\system\compile-server\projects_f1bd646f\timestamps\data
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:176)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:86)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:156)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:145)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:136)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:281)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

Comment: Please try this solution: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860239/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B2-idea-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-error-cannot-create-empty-file

Answer (score 1):

Translating y.bedrov comment - in Windows settings go to Region -> Administrative -> Change system locale -> Untick "Beta: Use Unicode..." option.