# IntelliJ Error on most simple applications

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have just downloaded IntelliJ for the first time, and I am just trying to do a simple "Hello World" test just so I can start becoming more comfortable with the program. But no matter what I try to do I keep getting this error whenever I build. I have looked online and cannot find anyone that has had the same problem. This is the error

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Cannot create empty file: 

C:\Users\brent\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\compile-server\test_88992a4c\timestamps\data
java.io.IOException: Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\brent\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\compile-server\test_88992a4c\timestamps\data
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:175)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:87)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:168)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:157)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:148)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:140)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

I do not know how to go about solving this. Did I install the IDE incorrectly? I have tried to do a full project rebuild like suggested but continue to get this error.

Last Timestamp from Log

```
    19-01-21 15:07:51,066 [  91274]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-01-21 15:07:52,938 [  93146]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1 
2019-01-21 15:08:32,284 [ 132492]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,221 [ 164429]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,221 [ 164429]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile C:\Users\brent\OneDrive\Documents\RS\Arkitoi\Arkitori Source\Arkitori Source 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,490 [ 164698]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - java.io.IOException: Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\brent\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\compile-server\arkitori_source_3dbf5cab\timestamps\data
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:175)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:87)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:168)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:157)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:148)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:140)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2019-01-21 15:09:04,559 [ 164767]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 1; warnings: 0 took 338 ms: 0 min 0sec 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,575 [ 164783]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader doesn't exist 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: Failed to configure logging: 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brent\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\log\build-log\build-log.properties (The system cannot find the path specified) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.ensureLogConfigExists(LogSetup.java:68) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.initLoggers(LogSetup.java:47) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.<clinit>(BuildMain.java:60) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,822 [ 165030]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58) 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,875 [ 165083]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk-11/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,875 [ 165083]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (#org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain). 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,875 [ 165083]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,875 [ 165083]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info. 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,922 [ 165130]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,922 [ 165130]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-01-21 15:09:04,922 [ 165130]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-01-21 15:09:05,855 [ 166063]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-01-21 15:09:05,855 [ 166063]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Community%20Edition%202018.3.3/lib/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-01-21 15:09:05,855 [ 166063]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-01-21 15:09:05,855 [ 166063]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-01-21 15:09:05,855 [ 166063]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-01-21 15:09:07,269 [ 167477]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1
```

Comment: It does look like a same issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243528/why-intellij-idea-pops-an-error-like-that

Comment: @manfromnowhere ah thanks I wasn't able to find that one. But unfortunately the solution provided there does not work for me.

Comment: Do you use any antivirus software?

Comment: @y.bedrov actually I just got a new computer and haven’t installed it yet. Is this potentially the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov I have installed anti-virus software and that did not fix the issue - I am not sure if that was supposed to fix it or not though lol

Comment: @brent_mb Can you provide the idea.log. 
You can do that with Help > Show Log in Explorer.

Comment: @hce I provided the most recent time stamps from the log in explorer at the bottom of the post

Comment: @brent_mb Have you tried to copy your project to another Location other than Onedrive (like a local harddrive) and build it from there? Also look for C:\Users\brent\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\log\build-log\build-log.properties if it exists.

Comment: @hce I have tried that. There is a default workspace that comes with IntelliJ called IntelliJProjects or something like that, and it is in a local hard drive and the same error comes up

Comment: @brent_mb Also look for C:\Users\brent\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\log\build-log\build-log.properties if it exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187071/discussion-between-brent-mb-and-hce).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't set JDK correctly.

Press F4 or right click project folder to open module setting

Click dependencies tab and make sure you have suitable SDK(jdk) selected.
Then click apply.