# IntelliJ : How to fix an cannot create an empty file error in <system>\compile-server\<project hash>\timestamps\data

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I took a Java course on uDemy and the teacher has recommended me a IntelliJ IDEA IDE so I installed me and was set off to a first project which was "Hello World" and so I runned it and it giving me this error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\Ivan Vukicevic\.IdeaIC2019.2\system\compile-server\helloworld_654f6f4d\timestamps\data
java.io.IOException: Cannot create empty file: C:\Users\Ivan Vukicevic\.IdeaIC2019.2\system\compile-server\helloworld_654f6f4d\timestamps\data
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:175)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:73)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:149)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:138)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:129)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:121)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:265)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not a single line of code, please take a look and edit ;)

Comment: Something wrong with IJ setup.  Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243528/why-intellij-idea-pops-an-error-like-that has a link to answer in Russian and there is comment that is from the translation.  Please try.

Comment: @azro : OP is learning new Java ; as part of it getting to know about IJ(IDE)  - He/she has written minimal code that reflects the problem -- It seems it is a problem in select locale.

Comment: Try starting your IDE by right clicking and choosing menuitem `Run as administrator` and see if this fixes this issue. On windows all applications are started without admin rights even if your local account has admin privileges. This is done for security reasons, but can be very annoying for developers as they their IDEs need admin rights on first startup.

Comment: It looks like you just don't have write access to your home directory. Idea is trying to write a temporary file in its cache (under .IdeaIC2019.2 in your home directory). If you can change the permissions on this directory to allow access to Intellij then it should work ok.